# Setting all array values to a single value

Tags: sas

I'd like to set all values in an array to 1 if some sort of condition is met, and perform a calculation if the condition isn't met. I'm using a do loop at the moment which is very slow.

I was wondering if there was a faster way.

```
data test2;
set test1;
array blah_{*} blah1-blah100;
array a_{*} a1-a100;
array b_{*} b1-b100;

do i=1 to 100;
blah_{i}=a_{i}/b_{i};
if b1=0 then blah_{i}=1;
end;

run;
```

I feel like the if statement is inefficient as I am setting the value 1 cell at a time. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to assign values to multiple variables at the same time in SAS. In fact  arrays are used as a solution to the inverse problem where instead of writing 100 assignment statements, the variables are grouped into an array and then assigned via a loop such as yours. If I still remember my undergrad assembly language classes correctly, I don't think any good compilers will actually make this kind of assignment any less efficient underneath the hood than having code that can assign multiple values at the same time in other languages. The syntax will be just more compact.

Comment: Why not just normalize your data structure?  Does everyone actually have values for all 100 of those A and B variables?  You might end up saving both space and complexity by using a vertical structure instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 100*NOBS assignments to do. Don't see how using a DO loop over an ARRAY is any more inefficient than any other way.

But there is no need to do the calculation when you know it will not be needed.

```
do i=1 to 100;
  if b1=0 then blah_{i}=1;
  else blah_{i}=a_{i}/b_{i};
end;
```

Comment: Static test first and `else` certainly are the big benefits here. Array processing involves run-time arithmetic to compute memory addresses or handles of value locations or variable slots in the PDV.  Extreme 'coding' would use macro to code generate 100 statements in which the variables are used directly instead of using an array.  The 'efficiency' is run-time loop removal and that the  'pdv slot' computation is performed once at compile time and instead of repeatedly per observation at run-time.  The inefficiency is complexity and future misunderstanding of the original source code.

Answer (score 1):

There are already several good answers, but for the sake of completeness, here is an extremely [silly and dangerous](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a001631548.htm#a002576889) way of changing all the array values at once without using a loop:

```
data test2;
set test1;
array blah_{*} blah1-blah100 (100*1);
array a_{*} a1-a100;
array b_{*} b1-b100;

/*Make a character copy of what an array of 100 1s looks like*/
length temp $800; *Allow 8 bytes per numeric variable;
retain temp;
if _n_ = 1 then temp = peekclong(addrlong(blah1), 800);

do i=1 to 100;
  blah_{i}=a_{i}/b_{i};
end;

/*Overwrite the array using the stored value from earlier*/
if b1=0 then call pokelong(temp,addrlong(blah1),800);

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a data set to "set" all values of an array without DOingOVER the array.  Note that using SET in this way changes INIT-TO-MISSING for array BLAH to don't.  I cannot comment on performance you will need to do your own testing.

```
data one;
   array blah[10];
   retain blah 1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;

data test1;
   do b1=0,1,0;
      output;
      end;
   run;

data test2;
   set test1;
   array blah[10]; 
   array a[10];
   array b[10];

   if b1 eq 0 then set one nobs=nobs point=nobs;
   else do i = 1 to dim(blah);
      blah[i] = i;
      end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: This makes the code a bit compact (2 less lines), but certainly much less efficient that assigning in a loop.

Comment: How do you know it is "certainly much less efficient"?

Comment: For starters a SET statement comes with certain overhead tasks like pointer initialization etc., whereas assignment just involves copying a value into memory. Also when using a SET statement, you are now performing additional operations like moving the data into a buffer and then into the PDV whereas such movements are completely eliminated when performing a simple assignment. The difference may not be much when working with small datasets, but you will start to see divergence when the amount of data involved becomes larger.

Comment: There are two neat things here.  The use of the `RETAIN array_name constant_value;` syntax to initializes multiple variables to the same value. Using a dataset as the source of default values makes it possible to generalize this method to other problems where the initial values for each variable is not constant, and perhaps generated by prior steps.

Comment: @PythonRSAS you're still only speculating.   Write a test program you will see your assumption is incorrect, in fact just the opposite.  That's why discussions of performance must always include testing.

Comment: @data_null_ - thanks for the feedback. I went on to test this as you suggested and I have posted the results as a separate answer. Always good to have someone challenge ones. I will admit that my blanket statement is flawed. However I think my assumptions were not flawed - some additional dynamics like how often the dataset is read into the buffer makes some of my points moot when processing large number of records..

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a response to the original question, but as a response to the discussion on the efficiency between using loops vs set to set the values for multiple variables**

Here is a simple experiment that I ran:

```
%let size = 100; /* Controls size of dataset */
%let iter = 1;   /* Just to emulate different number of records in the base dataset */

data static;
  array aa{&size} aa1 - aa&size (&size * 1);
run;

data inp;
  do ii = 1 to &iter;
    x = ranuni(234234);
    output;
  end;
run;

data eg1;
  set inp;

  array aa{&size} aa1 - aa&size;
  set static nobs=nobs point=nobs;

run;

data eg2;
  set inp;
  array aa{&size} aa1 - aa&size;
  do ii = 1 to &size;
    aa(ii) = 1;
  end;
run;
```

What I see when I run this with various values of &iter and &size is as follows:

As &size increases for a &iter value of 1, assignment method is faster than the SET.

However for a given &size, as iter increases (i.e. the number of times the set statement / loop is called), the speed of the SET approach increases while the assignment method starts to decrease at a certain point at which they cross. I think this is because the transfer from physical disk to buffer happens just once (since static is a relatively small dataset) whereas the assignment loop cost is fixed.

For this use case, where the fixed dataset used to set values will be smaller, I admit that SET will be faster especially when the logic needs to execute on multiple records on the input and the number of variables that needs to be assigned are relatively few. This however will not be the case if the dataset cannot be cached in memory between two records in which case the additional overhead of having to read it into the buffer can slow it down.

Comment: Any test on processing speed of statements and functions should **not** include an output dataset, and if possible, exclude other i/o inducing statements (such as SET, MERGE, UPDATE, MODIFY, OPEN, etc...) not pertinent to the benchmark.  My speculation is that it would be quite rare to encounter a condition in which a `SET` read causes the SAS or disk cache for `static` to be flushed.  Further protection of `static` can be ensured by pre-loading it with `SASFILE`

Answer (score 0):

I think this test isolates the statements of interest.

SUMMARY: 
SET+create init array 0.40 sec. + 0.03 sec, 
DO OVER array 11.64 sec.

```
NOTE: Additional host information:

 X64_SRV12 WIN 6.2.9200  Server

NOTE: SAS initialization used:
      real time           4.70 seconds
      cpu time            0.07 seconds

1          options fullstimer=1;
2          %let d=1e4; /*array size*/
3          %let s=1e5; /*reps (obs)*/
4          data one;
5             array blah[%sysevalf(&d,integer)];
6             retain blah 1;
7             run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.ONE has 1 observations and 10000 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      user cpu time       0.03 seconds
      system cpu time     0.00 seconds
      memory              7788.90k
      OS Memory           15232.00k
      Timestamp           08/17/2019 06:57:48 AM
      Step Count                        1  Switch Count  0


8          
9          sasfile one open;
NOTE: The file WORK.ONE.DATA has been opened by the SASFILE statement.
10         data _null_;
11            array blah[%sysevalf(&d,integer)];
12            do _n_ = 1 to &s;
13               set one nobs=nobs point=nobs;
14               end;
15            stop;
16            run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.40 seconds
      user cpu time       0.40 seconds
      system cpu time     0.00 seconds
      memory              7615.31k
      OS Memory           16980.00k
      Timestamp           08/17/2019 06:57:48 AM
      Step Count                        2  Switch Count  0


2                                                      The SAS System                         06:57 Saturday, August 17, 2019

17         sasfile one close;
NOTE: The file WORK.ONE.DATA has been closed by the SASFILE statement.
18         
19         data _null_;
20            array blah[%sysevalf(&d,integer)];
21            do _n_ = 1 to &s;
22               do i=1 to dim(blah); blah[i]=1; end;
23               end;
24            stop;
25            run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           11.64 seconds
      user cpu time       11.64 seconds
      system cpu time     0.00 seconds
      memory              3540.65k
      OS Memory           11084.00k
      Timestamp           08/17/2019 06:58:00 AM
      Step Count                        3  Switch Count  0


NOTE: SAS Institute Inc., SAS Campus Drive, Cary, NC USA 27513-2414
NOTE: The SAS System used:
      real time           16.78 seconds
      user cpu time       12.10 seconds
      system cpu time     0.04 seconds
      memory              15840.62k
      OS Memory           16980.00k
      Timestamp           08/17/2019 06:58:00 AM
      Step Count                        3  Switch Count  16
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more interesting tests results based on data *null* 's original test. I added the following test also:

```
%macro loop;

   data _null_;
     array blah[%sysevalf(&d,integer)] blah1 - blah&d;
     do _n_ = 1 to &s;
       %do i = 1 %to &d;
         blah&i = 1; 
       %end;
     end;
     stop;
   run;

%mend;

%loop;
```

```
d          s          SET Method (real/cpu)    %Loop (real/cpu)     array based(real/cpu)
100        1e5        0.03/0.01                0.00/0.00            0.07/0.07
100        1e8        11.16/9.51               4.78/4.78            1:22.38/1:21.81
500        1e5        0.03/0.04                0.02/0.01            Did not measure
500        1e8        16.53/15.18              32.17/31.62          Did not measure
1000       1e5        0.03/0.03                0.04/0.03            0.74/0.70
1000       1e8        20.24/18.65              42.58/42.46          Did not measure
```

So with array based assignments, it is not the assignment that is the big culprit itself. Since arrays use a memory map to map the original memory locations, it appears that the memory location lookup for a given subscript is what really impacts performance. A direct assignment avoids this and significantly improves performance.

So if your array size is in the lower 100s, then direct assignment may not be a bad way to go. SET becomes effective when the array sizes go beyond a few hundreds.